# MySQL Query to count Distinct Project IDs as a sum during the project duration

Tags: mysql

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Project_ID | Location |   status    | Start Date | End Date  |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|     122234 | aaaa     | ON HOLD     | 1/1/2019   | 1/10/2019 |
|     122235 | aaab     | IN PROGRESS | 1/1/2019   | 1/15/2019 |
|     122236 | aaac     | ON HOLD     | 1/5/2019   | 1/10/2019 |
|     122237 | aaad     | IN PROGRESS | 1/8/2019   | 2/1/2019  |
|     122238 | aaae     | IN PROGRESS | 1/12/2019  | 2/5/2019  |
|     122239 | aaaf     | ON HOLD     | 1/5/2019   | 1/15/2019 |
|     122240 | aaag     | IN PROGRESS | 1/1/2019   | 1/10/2019 |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

This is a very small sample of data, I have data that goes through 2020.

I need to count each of the ProjectIDs, which are in progress, during the date range between start and end and make a column call IN PROGRESS COUNT.  I cannot figure out how to count only while between the start and the end date.

Here is the query after thinking on it to see if I can use this:

```
SELECT 
    Project_ID,
    Location,
    Status, 
    'Start Date' AS Date_Type,
    `Start Date` AS Date,
    1 AS Count
FROM 
    Table
WHERE
    Status NOT IN ('COMPLETED')
AND
    `Snapshot` = (SELECT MAX(`Snapshot`) FROM Table)
GROUP BY 
    Project_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    Project_ID,
    Location,
    Status, 
    'End Date' AS Date_Type,
    `End Date` AS Date,
    -1 AS Count
FROM 
    Table
WHERE
    Status NOT IN ('COMPLETED')
AND
    `Snapshot` = (SELECT MAX(`Snapshot`) FROM Table)
GROUP BY 
    Project_ID
```

This should allow me, to use a running_sum of count to get the active projects.

Comment: Do you really have dates in your database in the format `1/8/2019` I only ask as that I assume mean they are NOT DATE data types, which of course means that all the normal simple date processing that MySQL does for free will not work

Comment: If start and end date are in range or start date is in range or end date is in range or range is between start and end date then you are interested

Comment: Riggs, no that is just me typing the human date in my brain.  the date format is YYYY-MM-DD and it knows they are a date field.  I am not having any luck getting started on the query yet, but I am still looking at code samples and seeing if I can find anything similar to poke with.  I very rarely count on SO for anything being fully solved or helped until I have almost got to the solution myself.

Comment: `select *, count(*) cnt, start_date, end_date
from table
where status = 'IN PROGRESS' and between start_date and end_date
group by Project_ID
`

Comment: That doesn't work quickSwap.  I think I may need a calendar table to join on so I can have a day by day count

Comment: It's not clear what you want if a status went from in progress to on hold in the date range.

Comment: and thanks to all of you for reminding me why I absolutely hate this discussion board.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you want if a status went from in progress to on hold in the date range.
But the core of this is if start and end date are in range or start date is in range or end date is in range or range is between start and end date then you are interested.

So given

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT * FROM T;
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Project_ID | Location | status      | Start_Date | End_Date   |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
|     122234 | aaaa     | ON HOLD     | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-10 |
|     122235 | aaab     | IN PROGRESS | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-15 |
|     122236 | aaac     | ON HOLD     | 2019-01-05 | 2019-01-10 |
|     122237 | aaad     | IN PROGRESS | 2019-01-08 | 2019-02-01 |
|     122238 | aaae     | IN PROGRESS | 2019-01-12 | 2019-02-05 |
|     122239 | aaaf     | ON HOLD     | 2019-01-05 | 2019-01-15 |
|     122240 | aaag     | IN PROGRESS | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-10 |
|     122240 | aaag     | on hold     | 2019-01-11 | 2019-01-12 |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This may do

```
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE STATUS = 'IN PROGRESS' AND
        (
        (START_DATE BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-02') OR
        (END_DATE BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-02') OR
        (START_DATE <= '2019-01-01' AND END_DATE >= '2019-01-02')
        );

+------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
| Project_ID | Location | status      | Start_Date | End_Date   |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
|     122235 | aaab     | IN PROGRESS | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-15 |
|     122240 | aaag     | IN PROGRESS | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-10 |
+------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```